# Javascript. Store Section's color and redistribute them. JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several sections with different colors in the background.

I need to dynamically create divs as a result of these sections.

So far I have no worries.

What I'm trying to get as a result, is that each divs has a different color in the background, taking the colors of the sections.

I can get this result with CSS

HTML:

```
<section class="l-section js-section"></section>
<section class="l-section js-section"></section>
<section class="l-section js-section"></section>
<section class="l-section js-section"></section>
<section class="l-section js-section"></section>

<div class="l-container-test js-container-test"></div>
```

SCSS:

```
.l-section{

     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;

     &:nth-child(1){

       background-color: red;

     }
     &:nth-child(2){

       background-color: green;

     }
     &:nth-child(3){

       background-color: yellow;

     }
     &:nth-child(4){

       background-color: blue;

     }
     &:nth-child(5){

       background-color: pink;

     }

    }

.l-container-test{

  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

    & > * {

      flex: 1;
    }

    & :nth-child(1){

      background-color: red;
    }
     & :nth-child(2){

      background-color: green;
    }
     & :nth-child(3){

      background-color: yellow;
    }

   // and so on....

}
```

JS:

```
function createDivs(){

    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let div = document.createElement(`div`);
    div.className = `l-div js-div`;

    const container = document.querySelector(`.js-container-test`);
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll(`.js-section`);
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll(`.js-div`);

    let arrColors = [];

    fragment.appendChild(div);

    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            container.appendChild(fragment.cloneNode(true));
    }

    sections.forEach(section => {

            colors = window.getComputedStyle(section).getPropertyValue(`background-color`);

        arrColors.push(colors)

    })

     console.log(arrColors);

    // EDIT
    arrColors.forEach((color, index) => {

            divs[index].style.backgroundColor = color;
    })

}

createDivs();
```

Here is my working example :   https://jsfiddle.net/CedGrvl/e476kvsn/40/

But I think it could be easier, unless I'm wrong, if I could handle these colors with js. In case I add divs, I would like the colors to follow each other.

Knowing that I still have more divs than sections, I would like the color sequence to be logical. If the sections from top to bottom are red, green, blue... the divs should be red, blue, green, red, blue, blue, green...

it is possible that I may be wrong in my logic, I am not necessarily looking for a pure and simple solution but at least some leads

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

I only manage to put the color on the first ones and I understand why. I have to figure out so that the other dives are colored.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured  it out

https://jsfiddle.net/CedGrvl/cp0zbx8t/1/

```
function createDivs(){

    const container = document.querySelector(`.js-container-test`);
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll(`.js-section`);

    let arrColors = [];
    let arrDivs = [];

    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = 'js-div';

    fragment.appendChild(div);

    sections.forEach(section => {

        let colors = window.getComputedStyle(section).getPropertyValue(`background-color`);
        arrColors.push(colors);

    });

    console.log(arrColors)

    function setNumberDivs(numberDiv){

        for(let i= 0; i < numberDiv; i++){

            container.appendChild(fragment.cloneNode(true));
            arrDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-div');


        }

        arrDivs.forEach((div, index) => {

            div.style.backgroundColor = arrColors[index%arrColors.length]
            console.log(index)
        })


        console.log(divs)
    }
    setNumberDivs(10);


}

createDivs();
```